# Regex for URL Redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, regex, url

Currently have a regex rule

```
^/connect\??(.*)
```

The purpose of this was to capture URLs with **/connect** or **/connect?whatever**. I'm now having an issue where **/connecticut** is getting captured, but I do not want it to. I've been playing around for a while, but having the query param on the URL is tripping me up in getting this to work. Anybody have any suggestions so that /connecticut is not captured, but the other two are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an optional group around `\?.*` and make the `?` obligatory inside it and add an end of string `$` anchor:

```
^\/connect(?:\?.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO4qL3/1)

*Pattern details*:

- `^`  - start of string
- `\/connect` - a literal substring `/connect`
- `(?:\?.*)?` - an optional group that matches 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `\?`  - a literal `?` symbol
  - `.*` - zero or more characters other than newline, as many as possible up to...
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: When testing the regex against multiline string at the online regex testers, not individual strings, you must use `g` and `m` modifiers.

Comment: This works beautifully. Thank you for the breakdown as well. It looks so simple now. I have never used the non-capturing group before, so this example really helps.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Comment: The non-capturing groups is used for grouping only, not for *capturing* some substring for using it later. It makes little difference here if you use a capturing or non-capturing group I believe, but a non-capturing is better.

Comment: I played around a little further using your example to get me started and I'm also able to capture the query params with the following: `^\/connect(\?(.*))?$` which captures the query param without the ? in group 2.

Comment: Yes, if that is necessary, you can use capturing groups inside a non-capturing one.